# Update a component from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm wondering if one can update the content of another component based on the events from another component.

I have a two react components. One of the components gets its data loaded to it when the page loads and the other component should have its data rendered based on the first components `onClick` method.

One of the components gets its data loaded to it from an API, that I then show in a list. I then have a method that should handle the clicked items called `itemClicked`, when an item gets clicked the data in the other component should update.

```
itemClicked = () => {
  // Get the ID of the clicked item, and use it in the other component
  console.log(e.target.attributes[0].value);
}

// ...

<ul>
    {items.map(item => (
        <li onClick={this.itemClicked} key={item._id} itemID={item._id}> {item.name} </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

I now this might be a bad question to ask, but I'm new to React and trying to learn a bit more about states and props.

Edit.

This is the parent component where I load the two components:

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentItem: {}
        }
    }
    
    onItemClick(item) {
          this.setState({
            currentItem: item
        })                                        
    
    }

    render() {
        return <>
            <div className='dashboard'>
                <div className='dashboard__wrapper'>
                    <SelectItem onItemClick="{this.onItemClick}" />
                    <EditItem item="{this.state.currentItem}" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    }
}

export default Dashboard
```

I updated the SelectItem component as well:

```
itemClicked = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.attributes[0].value);

    if (this.props.onItemClick) {
        this.props.onItemClick(e.target.attributes[0].value)
    }
}
```

But now it complains that this line:

```
this.props.onItemClick(e.target.attributes[0].value)
```

Isn't a function:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onItemClick is not a function
```

Comment: You should store the data that you need to share using a global state and the Context API.

Comment: It's a bit broad, but essentially what you want to do is *update state* in your click handler.  That state can be in a shared parent component, a context, a state manager like Redux, however you want to share state across components.  But the *event* updates the *state*, and the *UI* renders *from* the state.  The act of updating the state triggers the UI to re-render in React, that's basically its core functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.

If the list component and view component are both in same parent component. The parent component can have a state property e.g.`currentItem`. The `currentItem` will be set by passing a callback as property to the list component. The callback should be called when list item is clicked.

```
//List Component
itemClicked = () => {
  // Get the ID of the clicked item, and use it in the other component
  console.log(e.target.attributes[0].value);
  //call the callback
    if(this.props.onItemClick){
    
       this.props.onItemClick(e.target.attributes[0].value)
    }
}

...

<ul>
    {items.map(item => (
        <li onClick={this.itemClicked} key={item._id} itemID={item._id}> {item.name} </li>
    enter code here
    ))}
</ul>
```

Page Component

```
this.state = {
    currentItem: {}
}

onItemClick(item){
      this.setState({
        currentItem: item
    })                                        

}

render(){
   return <>
     <ListComponent onItemClick={this.onItemClick} />
     <ViewComponent item={this.state.currentItem} />
    </>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I updated the question with the error I now get.

Comment: It should be `onItemClick={this.onItemClick}` remove the quotes